# Android Picasso change image over certain time

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I am new to android application development. May I know how to load different images into one `ImageView` after 5 seconds?
Here is the code I wrote, but it only load once.

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService worker =
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

public void changeImage(){
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Picasso.with(c)
                        .load(arrPic.get(i))
                        .resize(300, 300)
                        .skipMemoryCache()
                        .into(iv)
            }
        };
        worker.schedule(task, 5*i, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you think is it a right way to use scheduler inside iterator??.

Comment: as of me the for(iterator) is not working after first start. the only scheduler is working. and the array gets only the i=0 each time.

Comment: I am not sure. I just found that is one way of delaying task to the desired timing. However, for the iterator it's working fine. It loops three time in the sequence of 1,2,3 and it's getting three different image from the array.

Comment: no as of me its not iterating data. when iterator starts and at first it reaches schedular task from there on schedular is working and iterator is paused.

Comment: I see. I am sorry I have misunderstood you. Now I understand what you mean. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create some variable/Objects

```
private int i = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();
private int DELAY = 5000;

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(i<arrPic.size()) {
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(arrPic.get(i))
                    .resize(300, 300)
                    .skipMemoryCache()
                    .into(imageView);
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, DELAY);
            i++;
        } else {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }
};
```

Call this method/line where you wants to start the imageView replace effect

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
```

Comment: try to increase the time length

Comment: I am sorry. I used a wrong way of testing the code just now. Actually in the total loop of three times, the Picasso only successfully loaded the image once which is the last image into the `ImageView`.

Comment: Nop. It is not working. I am trying to load each image into the `ImageView` after 5 seconds but it does not show anything. After 15 seconds only it loads the last image from the array into the `ImageView`.

Comment: try the same code after increase time interval. may be you have less time to download the image

Comment: I tried to increase to 10 seconds. But it still not working.

Comment: right actually it pauses the base thread for the time interval and resume after executing the whole method. will update you the right method to do same soon.